# Graphical boot ModeLine

Tags: boot, graphics

Bit of a weird requirement. I have an arcade machine running Linux.

The arcade monitor requires the video signal to be at 15khz, so I achieve this with a modeline in `xorg.conf`, it works great. There is a small PCB in the machine that will only let the correct video signal pass through to the monitor to prevent damage.

This system works, but if I ever want to see messages as the system boots, I need to plug in an external monitor that can display at a higher refresh rate. Once the X server starts then things become visible on the arcade monitor.

I'm OK with being unable to see message from the motherboard's BIOS, but what I would like to know is if there is any way to modify how the kernel outputs its messages. I know it's possible to have a graphical boot, but is it possible to run a custom modeline?

Comment: 1. That is awesome. 2. I've done something like this when the display provided an EDID, but something tells me an old arcade machine probably doesn't...

Comment: Yeah no EDID from this display. In fact I have to explicitly say that in my xorg.conf or nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps it might help:
http://www.fclose.com/2218/configuration-of-linux-kernel-video-mode/
http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/KernelModeSetting
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give this a try when I get a chance.